# assemblyBinding understanding Newtonsoft.Json and Common.Logging connection

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, nuget, app-config

I added to my project Newtonsoft.Json via Nuget.

After I did that I found VS added these section:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Q1: Why is it doing that? What is the purpose?

Q2: Why does Common.Logging appear there as well? I never added Common.Logging via Nuget.

Q3: Do I need to add Common.Logging via Nuget? I tried, installed Common.Logging via Nuget via Nuget and found out it also installed Common.Logging.Core. But the config section above did'n change!

Can someone explain me in very simple language without copy-pasting from MSDN what this whole circus is for? How does it work, and why Common.Logging suddenly was added to this section, do I actually need to install it along with Common.Logging.Core, when I need only Newtonsoft.Json?

Thanks.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Why is it doing that? What is the purpose?

Simple language is that if two components reference different versions of the same strong-named assembly, the runtime automatically adds a binding redirection to the newer version of the assembly in the output app configuration (app.config) file.

For example, you have application A that references library B, and also library C with version 1.0.0.0. Library B in turn also references library C, but the version 1.1.0.0. Now we have a conflict, because you cannot load different versions of the same assembly at runtime. To resolve this conflict you might use binding redirect.

If you are interested, you can see [Redirecting Assembly Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) for more details

> Q2: Why does Common.Logging appear there as well? I never added
>   Common.Logging via Nuget.

Not sure why it also add `Common.Logging`. It may be more related to your project. Probable, your project indirectly references this nuget package as reference or your project reference this assembly directly. Because `Add-BindingRedirect` will examines all assemblies within the output path for a project and adds binding redirects to the application or web configuration file where necessary.

Certify: [Add-BindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-add-bindingredirect)

> Q3: Do I need to add Common.Logging via Nuget? I tried, installed
>   Common.Logging via Nuget via Nuget and found out it also installed
>   Common.Logging.Core. But the config section above did'n change!

If you can make sure you only need `Newtonsoft.Json`, you do not need to add  Common.Logging via Nuget.

Hope this helps.